# Sending a file from 1c to the Flask server

Tags: python, flask, 1c

I have a problem sending a request from 1c to my server written in Flash Python.
Requests in text form come to the server without problems and are processed, but problems arise when I try to transfer a file. The program accepts a file in the files format (file = request.files['file']). How do I transfer a file from 1c so that the server understands and can process the file?

I tried to send a request directly using json from 1c. (I specified the path to the file and tried to encrypt it in base64)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.